# Spring Boot Application running inside Docker with mongodb and Java 11

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, dockerfile, java-11

I am running a simple spring-boot application inside a docker container. Here is my specifications:
- Spring boot 2.1.3.RELEASE
- Java 11 with Windows 10
- Docker use : FROM debian:stretch-slim as packager - ENV JDK_VERSION="11.0.1"

Spring boot simple applications works fine with above configuration

When I added Mongodb (Spring data mongo) and started the spring boor applications, it works good in my windows machine, but when I run inside docker container it is throwing error as follows:

==============================================

o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthIndicatorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDbFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoClientException: Unable to create JNDI context for resolving SRV records. The 'com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory' class is not available in this JRE
2019-03-10 06:18:58.201 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at com.eschoolo.EschooloCoreServiceApplication.main(EschooloCoreServiceApplication.java:24) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[eschoolo.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[eschoolo.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[eschoolo.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[eschoolo.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:125) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthIndicatorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDbFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoClientException: Unable to create JNDI context for resolving SRV records. The 'com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory' class is not available in this JRE
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1144) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:235) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:226) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:101) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:88) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:261) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:234) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDbFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoClientException: Unable to create JNDI context for resolving SRV records. The 'com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory' class is not available in this JRE
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305) ~

========================================================

I suspect, Spring Boot does npt support Java 11 completely or I am missing some Java module which I need to add to my Dockerfile.

As of now I have following java modules added to my dockerfile:

--add-modules \
       java.base,java.sql,java.naming,java.desktop,java.management,java.security.jgss,java.instrument

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: No, this is not a Spring Boot issue and – since you say is works on your Windows 10 environment but not inside the Docker container – I don't think it is a MongoDB issue either. My guess is that you have two different JREs on your Windows machine and inside your Docker container. Could you please tell us which?

Comment: Yes. Window machine I am using Oracle jdk 11. In the Docker container I am using Openjdk 11.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Docker image and its working fine now:

Here is the Dockerfile, useful if you want to setup Docker for Java 11 with maven.

```html
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim

ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.6.0
ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"
ARG SHA=fae9c12b570c3ba18116a4e26ea524b29f7279c17cbaadc3326ca72927368924d9131d11b9e851b8dc9162228b6fdea955446be41207a5cfc61283dd8a561d2f
ARG BASE_URL=https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
      curl procps \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Maven fails with 'Can't read cryptographic policy directory: unlimited'
# because it looks for $JAVA_HOME/conf/security/policy/unlimited but it is in
# /etc/java-9-openjdk/security/policy/unlimited
RUN ln -s /etc/java-11-openjdk /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-$(dpkg --print-architecture)/conf

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
  && curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz ${BASE_URL}/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz \
  && echo "${SHA}  /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
  && tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  && rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"

COPY mvn-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh
COPY settings-docker.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["mvn"]

CMD ["mvn", "clean","package","-Dmaven.test.skip=true"]

# COPY --from=packager "$JAVA_HOME" "$JAVA_HOME"
COPY "target/*.jar" "/myspringbootapp.jar"

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "-jar", "/myspringbootapp.jar" ]
ENTRYPOINT [ "java" ]
```